# ¿Cómo soluciono esto ./ciclo.sh: línea 3: error sintáctico cerca del elemento inesperado `$'\r'' '/ciclo.sh: línea 3: `for ((i=1; i<=50;i++));?

Tags: sh

Al momento de querer realizar un bucle anidado en cygwin me marca este error. Alguien que me podría ayudar

```
#!/bin/bash
arreglo="50 100 150 200 250 300 350 400 450 500"
for ((i=1; i<=50;i++));
do
    for j in $arreglo;
    do
        gams Cafe-T$i-D(arreglo[$j-1]).gms
    done
done
```

Quiero correr todos los programas a la vez, soy nuevo en esto, porfavor ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Borre el ;

```
for ((i = 1; i<=50; i++))
do
```